# Set quality of YouTube video in MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have managed to display a YouTube video in `MPMoviePlayerController`. Now I want to set different quality of the video just as YouTube has done it.

I am using LBYoutubeextractor to display video in MPMoviePlayer from youtube.

[image]

As in the image above, I want to enable the user to change video quality by clicking on various pixel options, like 1080pHD, 720pHD, etc.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I guess there is no automatic way to achieve it. You need to handle button taps and then ask for different resolution videos.

Comment: but then the video will begin from start, i don't want that, plus i am using LBYoutubeextractor to display video in MPMoviePlayer from youtube.